# SharePoint 2013 custom action multiple selected items?

Tags: list, document-library

I have a `Document Library`. I would like to create some custom actions in the ribbon which is doing some logic for the selected documents.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is late, but here's a quick & dirty workaround to achieve such a behaviour: 
[Use View Ribbon Custom Action on Multiple List Items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35935/use-view-ribbon-custom-action-on-multiple-list-items)

The main tricks:

SPD creates the UserCustomActions definition for the list with code to only display for a single item. Using SP Manager, you can simply edit the script to allow for any number of selected items to enable the icon in the ribbon. (Changed ==1 to >0)

[image]

[image]